# Basic Fourier Series properties question.e.5

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

On the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ consider the function, $$ f(\theta) = \begin{cases}
0 & \texttt{if $|\theta|>\delta$}, \\
1-\frac{|\theta|}{\delta} & \texttt{if$|\theta| \le \delta$.}
\end{cases} $$

Show that $$f(\theta) = \frac{\delta}{2\pi} + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 - \cos n\delta}{n^{2}\pi \delta} \cos n\theta.$$

I know that I will use the following definition of the Fourier Series,$$f(\theta) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n) e^{in\theta}$$

where the Fourier Coefficient is given by,$$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta) e^{-in\theta} d\theta,$$

And I wrote the detailed definition of the function as follows:$$ f(\theta) = \begin{cases}
0 & \texttt{if $\theta<-\delta \ and \ \theta>\delta $}, \\
1-\frac{\theta}{\delta} & \texttt{if$-\delta \le \theta \le \delta$  and $\theta$  is +ve.},\\
1+\frac{\theta}{\delta} & \texttt{if$-\delta \le \theta \le \delta$  and $\theta$  is -ve..}
\end{cases}. $$

I am not sure if this detailed definition is right? And if there is a simpler one? I do not know exactly How to divide the interval of integration while calculating $\hat{f}(n)$? What is the relation between $\delta$ and the interval $[-\pi , \pi]?$ Is $\delta$ a very small positive quantity inside the interval as we know?

Could anyone tackle this with me?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write why it's an inner product in a seperate answer:

Given $[a,b] ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ ,Define the vector space $V=C([a,b],\mathbb{C})$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

I'll show that $<,>:V \times V\to \mathbb{C}$, $<f,g>:=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{t=a}^b f(t) \overline {g(t)}dt$ is an inner product on $V$. I'll note that $C([a,b],\mathbb{C})$ are the continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

(i) Linearity in the first argument: This is immediate due to linearity of the integral.

(ii) Conjugate symmetry:

$\overline {<f,g>}= \overline{\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{t=a}^b f(t) \overline {g(t)}dt}= \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{t=a}^b \overline{f(t) \overline {g(t)}}dt=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{t=a}^b \overline{f(t)} g(t)dt=<g,f>$

(iii) Positive-definiteness:

$<f,f>=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{t=a}^b f(t) \overline {f(t)}dt=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{t=a}^b |f(t)|^2 dt$

$|f(t)|^2 $ is a positive integrable function and therefore $<f,f> \geq0$. Also from the fact that $f$ is continuous we get that $\int_{t=a}^b |f(t)|^2 dt=0$ if and only if $f(t)=0$ for every $t \in [a,b]$.

I hope this ansers the question about (2).

Answer (score 1):

You could actually use the hilbert base {$cos(nx)$,$sin(nx)$} instead. While remembering that you could write: $f(x)=\sum a_n cos(nx) +\sum b_n sin(nx)$.
You should remember also that $a_n=\frac{<f,cos(nx)>}{<cos(nx),cos(nx)>}$ and $b_n=\frac{<f,sin(nx)>}{<sin(nx),sin(nx)>}$.

Comment: I should add that you can quickly see that $b_n=0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What courses did you studied related to Fourier series? I did not know what is the meaning of Hilbert base? I did not understand alot of your words. What is your backgroud ?

Comment: Introduction to functional analysis.

Comment: From which book?

Comment: how did u know that the Hilbert base is as u said?

Comment: It's a book in my native tongue so it won't neccesarily do you much good, However I should note you can get the represention I said from your question by using euler identity.
That is:
$\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i} =sin(nx)$ , and $\frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}{2} =cos(nx)$

Comment: It does not matter the language of the book, Tell me Its name if you do not mind. What is your mother tongue? may be we both have the same mother tongue so I could read the book.

Comment: How could I quickly see that $b_{n} = 0 $ for every n \in mathbb{N}? could u clarify for me ?

Comment: $sin(nx)$ is an odd function, and the function you defined is even. From that you get that $f(x)sin(nx)$ is an odd function.
Therefore the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta) sin(n\theta) d\theta=0$, which means $<f,sin(nx)>=0$.

Comment: I'll just note that $<f,g>=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta) g(\theta) d\theta$, since you're dealing with real functions.

Comment: you are using inner product and we are not necessarily in a Hilbert space.

Comment: you mean that I will not use the Fourier Series Definition that I mentioned...right?

Comment: please if u do not mind answer the questions that I am asking above in my Question... thanks.

Comment: Could u please clarify (5) that you stated while talking about Hilbert spaces.... thanks.

Comment: By clarifying (5), do you mean showing that it is indeed a hilbert space?

Comment: No, I mean write $\sum d_{n}$ as $\sum a_n$ + $\sum b_{n}$

Comment: Please, if you liked my question vote it up.

Comment: The {$d_n$}$_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is simply {$\hat{f} (n)$}$_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$, maybe that was the source of confusion.

Comment: If you like any of my comments please vote them up.... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll clarify some things which might have been unclear:

(1) A hilbert space is a complete inner product space

(2) Integrating the product of two continuous functions over a segment gives you an inner product space

(3) Every inner product space can be completed such that the new inner product agrees with the original inner product on the original space (meaning the set)

(4) Every Hilbert space $H$ has a set of orthonormal vectors {$v_i$}$_{i\in I}$ such that for every $u \in H$ if $<u,v_i>=0$ for every $i\in I$, then $u=0$. That set is called a hilbert base of $H$.

(5) You can write $\sum \hat{f}(n) e^{inx}$ as $\sum a_n\frac{(e^{inx}+e^{-inx})}{2}+ \sum b_n\frac{(e^{inx}-e^{-inx})}{2i}$ 
and get a formula for $a_n$ and $b_n$ dependent on $\hat{f}(n)$ acoordingly:
 $a_n=\frac{\hat{f}(-n)+\hat{f}(n)}{2}$,  $b_n=\frac{\hat{f}(-n)-\hat{f}(n)}{2i}$

$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f(\theta) \cos(n\theta) d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \cos(n\theta) d\theta+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{0} \frac{\theta}{\delta} \cos(n\theta) d\theta+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\delta} -\frac{\theta}{\delta} \cos(n\theta) d\theta$

While $b_n=0$  for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But still can be expressed as:

$b_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f(\theta) \sin(n\theta) d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \sin(n\theta) d\theta+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{0} \frac{\theta}{\delta} \sin(n\theta) d\theta+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\delta} -\frac{\theta}{\delta} \sin(n\theta) d\theta$

(6) Given a hilbert base {$u_i$}$_{i \in I}$, you can write every $v \in H$ as $\sum_{i \in I} <v,u_i>u_i$. The set  {$\sin(nx)$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$,{$\cos(nx)$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Hilbert base for the space $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ which contains the function $f$.

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: But now, if I used what u said, How could I divide the interval of integration?

Comment: My question was not about the integration but about the boundaries, How I will define them? please if you do not mind answer my point not any other thing.

Comment: The integration that you have to do is:
 $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta) cos(n\theta) d\theta$, which equals:

But you can notice that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta) cos(n\theta) d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f(\theta) cos(n\theta) d\theta$

And then: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f(\theta) cos(n\theta) d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} cos(n\theta) d\theta+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\delta}^{0} \frac{\theta}{\delta} cos(n\theta) d\theta+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} -\frac{\theta}{\delta} cos(n\theta) d\theta$.

Comment: Could u prove for me the definition of Fourier Coefficient that u use from the definition that I mentioned above in the question ?

Comment: please put \ before cosine and sine so that it does not appear italic....  ...thanks.

Comment: It won't let me edit it further.

But for the fourier cooeficent:

$a_0=\hat{f}(0)$


$a_n=\frac{\hat{f}(-n)+\hat{f}(n)}{2}$.

I'm assuming that's what you meant.

Comment: the boundaries in the last line in your previous comment are not clear for me ........Could u clarify? or either correct the mistake in them.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: I mean the above comment of u that I voted up, the last integration boundaries is from 0 to $\pi$, Do u really mean this ?

Comment: No the correct version is edited into the answer,

The last integration boundary should be until $\delta$.

Comment: .....Could u proof number (2) in your answer please ?